# Visual Studio 2008 - Customise right click menu

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to customise the right click menu in VS2008 through the UI?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

The easiest way is to record a macro and then bind it to the context menu.

I've found [this](http://www.sharpregion.com/blog/?p=105) post very helpful doing this.